# How can I format this awk command?

Tags: awk

```
$ echo "$(lastlog | grep $USER | awk '{print $(NF-5)" "$(NF-3)" "$(NF-4)" "$(NF-2)" "$(NF-1)" "$(NF-0)}')"
Thu 7 Sep 05:56:35 +0100 2023
```

I want to replace the `+0100` bit with `BST` or `GMT` if the value is `+0000` (I am aware that this output is probably dependent on the locale).

I did test for the value of `$(NF-1)` to conditionally set a variable, but I don't know how to put the variable within the awk print command.

I also want to put an extra space between `$(NF-5)` and `$(NF-3)` when `$(NF-3)` (the date) is a single digit, but not when it is two digits.

How best can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time zone, I'd suggest adding an `if`-statement, since you want to check for two possible values:

```
if($(NF-1)=="+0000") {zone="GMT"}
else if ($(NF-1)=="+0100") {zone="BST"}
else {zone=$(NF-1)}
```

Then print the `zone` variable as defined above. (`print zone`)

The if-statement cannot be put into a `print` / `printf` command directly, whereas if you had only one change e.g. `+0000` -> `GMT` this would work:

```
print $(NF-1)=="+0000"?"GMT":$(NF-1)
```

For space-padding `$(NF-3)`, the sound way is using `printf`.

```
printf "%2s",$(NF-3)
```

In summary:

```
awk '{
    if($(NF-1)=="+0000") {zone="GMT"}
    else if ($(NF-1)=="+0100") {zone="BST"}
    else {zone=$(NF-1)}

    printf "%s %2s %s %s %s %s",$(NF-5),$(NF-3),$(NF-4),$(NF-2),zone,$(NF-0)
}'
```

Comment: `$(NF-1)=="+0000"?"GMT":$(NF-1)=="+0100"?"BST":"$(NF-1)` works for two changes, although it starts to get unesthetic